# Index Management.How I can reindex all things?

Tags: magento2

How I can reindex all things?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to reindex in magento 2, go to the CLI and then the root folder of your magento installation and run the below command :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```